# Regex match new line until

Tags: regex

Struggling with this one.... This is my data, I want to select all from the first data-group until the next

Original

```
data-group object name
1234
5677
7890
12356
data-group object name2
```

Desired Output

```
data-group object name
1234
5677
7890
12356
```

I'm currently looking into positive look ahead, and have come up with the following expression

```
(?=data-group)data-group
```

This selects.

```
data-group
data-group
```

How do I get it to match anything between on the new line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DOTAll` modifier `(?s)` inorder to make dot to match line breaks.

```
(?s)\bdata-group\b.*?(?=\bdata-group\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yD8vZ3/2)

**OR**

This won't print an extra newline character at the last.

```
(?s)\bdata-group\b.*?(?=\ndata-group\b)
```

Use `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?` if your lang won't support s modifier. `[\s\S]*?` matches any space or non-space character zero or more times non-greedily.

```
\bdata-group\b[\s\S]*?(?=\ndata-group\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yD8vZ3/3)